# Dragging an image on the canvas?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I am working on the canvas where user can draw and place images on the canvas. I implemented that user can draw something on canvas using his finger. My question is, User want to drag an image on the canvas at a specific location where user want to place and continue his drawing on the canvas.

Comment: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: i need to drag and drop the image on the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` you check if the touch was on the image/bitmap

during `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` you change the left and top variables of

`public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)`

and in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you release the pic